# ABI compatibility of different C/C++ language versions + GNU extensions

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I'm currently using gcc 4.8.2 with no std option to compile my c/c++ code.
Now I would like to use some of the new C/C++ features that are provided by the newer language versions of c/c++.

(Un?)Fortunately gcc understands many flavors of C/C++:

- c90, c99, c11, gnu90, gnu99, gnu11
- c++98, c++03, c++11, gnu++98, gnu++03, gnu++11

---

Currently I'm asking myself:

- **Do I need for every c/c++ version a separate library or is it possible to use one library for multiple C/C++ versions?**
- **Especially can I link a libary compiled with a specific c/c++ version, when I use the corresponding c/c++-version with the gnu extensions?**

---

**Clarification (based on the comments)**

Please note, that I'm using just one compiler. Not two gcc's that only differ in the revision number.
I'm only asking for ABI incompatibilities between the different std-options, when using only one gcc compiler.

Comment: The flavour of language itself shouldn't change the ABI, just different versions of the compiler itself. You probably don't want to combine the new compiler with libraries compiled with a compiler before around 4.6, but reasonably modern versions of gcc are compatible with each other (at least on x86). [Most of the C++ standard template library is implemented in headers - since it's "templates", so should compile just fine with whatever version of language the compiler and headers are compatible with]

Comment: The ABI changed a lot already. From gcc 4.8.1 rev1 to 4.8.1 rev5, I had to recompile my entire static library in order for it to link. Otherwise it gives me undefined symbols, etc.. From 4.7.2 to 4.8.1 is even worse. If it is a dynamic library (.dll or .so) then linking is done at run-time and works just fine. Only worries is about CRT versions and is rare that you'd have a crash/problem. For static libraries (.a or .lib or .o), it is a nightmare.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - This might be a reasonable assumption for the C ABI, but in theory the `-std` option could invoke different linker options. I wouldn't depend on C++ runtime library compatibility between minor releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

- **No** you can't combine different language versions in the same program, this will cause "One Definition Rule" violations in many library headers.

You may find in limited cases that a few classes actually don't change with the language version.  However this is rare, rvalue references are required by the C++11 Standard, and not available in C++03 mode at all.

As for versions with and without support for GNU extensions, you're likely to have more success, but you will still need to run each header through the preprocessor and verify that the exact same sequence of tokens is seen by the compiler using both options.

And that's completely apart from ABI changes, that could cause memory layout or name mangling to differ between compiler variants.

You can also avoid one-definition rule violations on your own public APIs by avoiding using any version and language-specific features.  Essentially, this means a flat C API.